# 2 posts same excerpt?

Tags: excerpt

I'm facing the following problem: I'm outputting 2 posts with different titles, dates, permalinks but the excerpt are both the same.

```
        <?php
    $query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => array( 'events' )));

    $months = array("", "januari", "februari", "maart", "april", "mei", "juni", "juli", "augustus", "september", "oktober", "november", "december");

    function sortFunction( $a, $b ) {
        return $a["date"] - $b["date"];
    }

    while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
            $date = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'date');        
            $id = get_the_ID();

            $tosortposts []= array(
                'date' => strtotime($date[0]),
                'link' => get_permalink($id), 
                'title' => get_the_title($id), 
                'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(5)
            );

    endwhile;

    usort($tosortposts, "sortFunction");

    foreach($tosortposts as $p){

            echo '<h3><a href="'; echo $p['link']; echo '">';
            echo ''; echo $p['title']; echo '</a></h3><p>';
            echo date('j ', $p['date']).$months[date("n", $p['date'])].'</p>';                      

                echo excerpt(35);

            echo '<p>&#187; <a href="'; echo $p['link']; echo '"> Lees meer over dit evenement </a></p>';
    }
    ?>


<?php endwhile; ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is `get_the_excerpt(5)`

Comment: `get_the_excerpt()` does not accept any parameters. The parameters have been long time depreciated

Comment: Thanks pieter, but how am I going to get the content and limit the text? Thats what the excerpt is for right?

Comment: Yes you are right. Simply call `the_excerpt()`. If you need to customize it, feel free and check out, I've done a post on that, Allow HTML in excerpts. Just search